# How to cancel firebase async requests in flutter instead of checking mounted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, flutter, future

I have a flutter app talking to the Firebase Realtime Database.  I get the data asynchronously, obviously, but my UI allows the user to move to a different part of the app, which means by the time the request completes, the `Widget` may be unmounted.  Best practices say to cancel the async work instead of checking the `mounted` property but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this for some reason.

```
@override void initState() {
  super.initState();

  firebaseRealtimeReference.child('myData').once().then((results) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _myLocalData = results;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Alternately with async/await: */
  _myLocalData = firebaseRealtimeDatabaseReference.child('myData').once();
}

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MyWidget(_myLocalData);
}

@override dispose() {
  // Instead of checking mounted in the future, I should instead
  // cancel the work in progress here.
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Futures are not cancelable, therefore using `mounted` is probably the right choice. There is also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-async_async/CancelableOperation-class.html but I'm not sure it buys you anything for this use case.

Comment: This seems unfortunate.  It is strange that Firebase wouldn't provide a mechanism to use best practices.  I wonder if there is a different way to go about this.